# breaking permutation of 1 to n number in 2 set

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

problem link : https://codeforces.com/contest/1295/problem/E

this problem states that there is permutation of 1 to n number such that every number occur only once

eg. p = [ 1,2,3] or [2,1,3] for n = 3.

now for every permutation in p there is a cost c<sub>i</sub> for the i<sup>th</sup> element of permutation p. whenever I move the i<sup>th</sup> element form one set to another i have to pay c<sub>i</sub>.

So, the question asks me to break the permutation in two set at any position k such that 1 <= k < n. Basically no set should be empty. Now the condition is that each element of set1 = (1 to k) should be less from set2 = (k+1, n). so to do so i have two operation , either i can move an element from set1 to set2 or vice versa. performin this operation on ith element wold cost me the ci amount. If either set1 or set2 is empty the condition is met.

eg

> p = [3,1,2]   c = [7,1,4].
>
> set1 = [3,1]  & set2 = [2].
>   so now we can send 2 from set2 to set1 with minimum cost of 4.

for more example please refer to problem. Link is above.

my approach :

> for any k we need to have 1 to k element in set1 and rest in set2.
>   So lets start from `i = 1` and keep on moving till `i = n-1` && at every position I maintain the pfx ans.
>   To calculate the pfx array at every `pos = i` if the `p[i] > i` then we need to add the cost because we have to transfer the element to `set2` and if it is less than `i` then we need to substract because we wanted it before so we had it in our total cost. but now we don't want it to be in our cost since we have the value. similarly I have also calculated for every position if I had the cur value or not.

here is my code. It passes many test cases but keeps on failing at 10th. cant understand the reason.

help please.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define ll unsigned long long
#define pii pair<int,int>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ll n , ans, prc3=0;
    cin>>n;
    vector<ll> p(n+1),a(n+1);

    for(ll i=1; i<=n; i++) cin>>p[i];
    for(ll i=1; i<=n; i++) cin>>a[p[i]], prc3 += a[p[i]];

    ll prc1=0, prc2=0;
    ll ans1=INT_MAX, ans2=INT_MAX, ans3=INT_MAX;

    vector<bool> vst(n+1,false);

    for(ll i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(p[i]>i)
        {
            prc1 += a[p[i]];
        }
        else if(p[i]<i)
        {
            prc1 -= a[p[i]];
        }

        if(vst[i])
        {
            prc1 -= a[i];
        }

        vst[p[i]] = true;

        if(!vst[i])
        {
            prc1 += a[i];
        }

        ans1 = min(ans1,prc1);

        prc2 += a[p[i]];

        ans2 = min(ans2,prc2);

        prc3 -= a[p[i]];

        ans3 = min(ans3,prc3);


    }

    ans = min(ans1,ans2);
    ans = min(ans,ans3);

    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you have it, you should add the input from the tenth test case to the question.

Comment: By the way, be really careful combining `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` with `using namespace std;` It can be a source of many magical mystery bugs.

Comment: You're mostly dealing with professional developers here, not competitive programmers, so you're going to need to remove cancer code such as the first four lines of your program if you want your code to be readable.

Comment: @user4581301 no that never causes the problem and the 10 th case has more than 18000 elements with whooping value of 1e9

Comment: See if you have any of the vector marching out of bounds by replacing the `[]` operators with the`at` method or running the tenth test case through valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is attempting to do exactly, but from struggling with this question myself and finally reading the [editorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/73467), it seems to me that achieving a solution within the constraints requires a tree data structure.

As I understand, we keep a variable, `k`, that represents the highest number in the left side. We start `k` at 1 and we iterate up to `n`. At the same time, we keep a tree, where each key, `i`, points to the cost of creating the current `k` partition starting at position `i`.

When we increment `k`, all the `i`s that are the partition starting-positions greater than or equal to the position of `k` in the starting list will not need that element moved so we update all those `i`s, subtracting `A[p[k]]` from each one in `O(log n)` time using the tree; and update all the `i`s that point to partition starting-positions less than `k`, adding the cost of that move to each one. We take the minimum cost on each iteration.

As far as I know, updates on a segment in `O(log n)` time would require a tree data structure.